# "Git stash apply" all files, except one

Tags: git, git-stash

I made a stash of multiple files (30 +) using git stash. I now want to apply the stash to all files except one. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your best bet is to probably to `git stash apply` then `git checkout -- [file]` to remove the changes applied when applying the stash.

If you have changes in the file already, your best bet is to commit them before applying the stash, you could then rebase the commit and the stash into a single commit later if you wished.

Comment: Additional point here: if after running apply (assuming clean working tree first), you have a conflict in the file in question - scenario for me was I had made multiple project file changes since the stash, so wanted to get my stash back, but ignore its project file changes since I could easily do them again on top - then git won't let you checkout the file, since it is unmerged/conflicted. You have to `git checkout --ours XYZ.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` ours in this case being the branch you are currently on, and pulling the stash into.

Answer (score 5):

You can stage the file you want to preserve by doing

```bash
git add <file>
```

and then use

```bash
git stash push --keep-index
```

This will stash everything but staged files.

Comment: or `git stash push --keep-index -u` if you unstaged files as well. +1

Answer (score 2):

I have a workaround answer.
Commit the file.
Git stash.
Revert the commit.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea because if someone does not want git to track that file it will start tracking it. I guess if someone did want to avoid reverting (which would pollute the git history) you could reset soft the head with `git reset --soft HEAD~1` which will take your staged commit and unstage it. i'm not sure if that removes the git tracking or not.